# Uploading to s3, using s3 servers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-s3

Does anyone have any sample code (preferrably in rails) that uploads to s3, using s3's servers.

Again, uploading directly to s3, where the actual upload/streaming is also preformed on amazon's servers.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/16537396/165673

Answer (score 3):

Requirements:

- Plupload, jQuery

Idea:

- Authorize Upload via your app (sign it on server-side)
- Use the signed request to upload the file to S3
- Notify your app that the upload is done
- Check whether S3 has received the file

I posted the code as a [gist at https://gist.github.com/759939](https://gist.github.com/759939), it misses commments and you might run into some issues due to missing methods (had to rip it from our codebase).

`stored_file.rb` contains a model for your DB. Has many of paperclips helper methods inlined (which we used before we switched to direct upload to S3).

I hope you can use it as a sample to get your stuff running.

Comment: Approximately 2-3 days of work some months ago. But happy to share it (I also submitted a patch to plupload because of issues I had during implementation).

Answer (score 1):

If you are using Rails 3, please check out my sample projects:

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash and MooTools-based FancyUploader to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-FancyUploader

Sample project using Rails 3, Flash/Silverlight/GoogleGears/BrowserPlus and jQuery-based Plupload to upload directly to S3: https://github.com/iwasrobbed/Rails3-S3-Uploader-Plupload

Answer (score 0):

To simply copy files, this is easy to use:
[Smart Copy Script into S3](http://devblog.famundo.com/articles/2007/03/12/cp2s3-a-command-line-smart-copy-script-into-s3)

Answer (score 0):

Amazon wrote a Ruby library for the S3 REST API. I haven't used it yet.

http://amazon.rubyforge.org/